# Cо́здал или созда́л — как правильно?

Tags: орфоэпия, глаголы

*Этот писатель **со́здал** новый язык* или *Этот писатель **созда́л** новый язык*.
Как правильно сказать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Верны оба варианта -- и со́здал, и создáл, однако старшей орфоэпической норме соответствует ударение на первый слог; форма с последним ударным слогом снабжается пометой *допустимое* в словарях.

[*Интернет-источник*](http://xn----8sbhebeda0a3c5a7a.xn--p1ai/%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB/)

Comment: То, что именуют (допускаемым) _старшей нормой_, обычно противопоставляется современному литературному языку (т. е. младшей норме) - с допущением получилось наоборот.

Comment: @Alex_ander с трудом улавливаю вашу мысль...

Comment: Если в словаре что-то называют "допустимым", то оно  соответствует не текущей норме, а чему-то другому (старшая норма = старомосковское произношение; младшая - современная). В данном случае ударение на первом слоге соответствует _современной норме_  (а не старшей, если она отличается), а на втором - _допускается_.

Comment: @Alex_ander не могу с вами согласиться: словарная фиксация ударения на первый слог старше (см. словарь Ушакова начала XX века), тогда как ударение на последний слог стало фиксироваться как допустимое относительно недавно. Именно такое распределение и говорит о том, что есть старшая и младшая норма. Может, вы хотели уличить меня в подмене понятий (старшая = главная), однако, к счастью, здесь я не ошибся.

Comment: @Alex_ander более того, иногда помета _допустимо_ соответствует именно младшей норме. Обратите внимание на то, что в некоторых словарях (например, Каленчук М.Л., Касаткина Р.Ф. Словарь трудностей русского произношения: Около 15000 слов 2001 г.) даже введены три разных вида допустимых форм: _допуст. устар., допуст. новое, допуст. разг._.

Comment: Спасибо, это проясняет реальное действие двух норм (я исходил из упрощённого определения, недавно попавшегося на глаза).

Answer (score 2):

Словари второй вариант (с ударением на втором слоге) считают "допустимым", "разговорным" (что странно - ударение обычно проявляется в устной речи) или равноценным (т. е. оставляют без пометок).

На мой взгляд, *полезно* употребление слова дифференцировать по ударению в зависимости от того, высокий или "низмененный" требуется оттенок, ведь *созидание* и *создание* (давки, трудностей) заметно разнятся:

> Этот писатель со́здал новый язык.
>
> Пользователь создáл папку на диске С.